# Adding and subtracting exact values to float

Tags: java, floating-point

**Question:**

The total amount of floating points is finite, there's about 2^32 of them. With a float, you can go directly to the next or previous one using `java.lang.Math.nextAfter`. I call that a single *leap*. My main quesion, composed of sub questions is, **how can I navigate on floats using leaps ?**

[image: Float navigation]

First, how can I move a float to another with multiple leaps at once ?

```
public static float moveFloat(float value, int leaps) {
    for(int i = 0; i < Math.abs(leaps); i++)
        value = Math.nextAfter(value, Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY * signum(leaps));
    return value;
}
```

That way should work on theory but is really unoptimized. How can I do it in a single addition ?

I also need to know how much leaps there's between 2 floats. Here's the example implementation for this one:

```
public static int getLeaps(float value, float destination) {
    int leaps = 0;
    float direction = signum(destination - value);

    while(value * direction < destination * direction) {
        value = Math.nextAfter(value, Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY * direction);
        leaps++;
    }

    return leaps;
}
```

Again, same problem here. This implementation isn't suitable.

**Extra:**

The thing I call a *leap*, does it have an actual name ?

**Background:**

I'm trying to make a simple 2D physics engine in Java and I have trouble with my floating point operations. I learned about relative error float comparison and it helped a bit but it's not magic. What I want is to be exact with my floating points.

I already know a lot of base ten numbers cannot be exactly represented with floating points but execptionally, I don't care. All I want is exact `float` arithmetic in base 2.

To simplify, in my collision detection and response process, I check if shapes overlap (let's stay in one dimension for this example) and I replace the 2 shapes overlapping using their weight.

See this example:
[image: One dimensional collision detection and resolving]

If the black lines are the `float` values(and the space between each other leaps) whatever the precision is, I want to place both shapes (colored lines) to be exactly at the brown position. (The brown position is determined by the weights ratio and by rounding. What I call penetration is the overlaping area/distance. If the penetration would of been 5, red would been pushed by 1 and blue by 4).

The problem is, do to that I have to keep the penetration of the collision (in this case the penetration is exactly the ULP of the float, or 1 leap) in a float and I suspect this leads to inexactitude. If the penetration value is bigger than the coordinates of the shapes, it will be less precise so they won't be exactly replaced at the good coordinate.

What I imagine is to keep the penetration of the collision as the amount of leaps I need to get from one to the another and use it afterwards.

This is a simplified version of the current code I have:

```
public class ReplaceResolver implements CollisionResolver {
    @Override
    public void resolve(Collision collision) {
        float deltaB = collision.weightRatio * collision.penetration; //bodyA's weight over the sum of the 2 (pre calculated)
        float deltaA = 1f - deltaB;

        //the normal indicates where the shape should be pushed. For now, my engine is only AA so a component of the normal (x or y) is always 0 while the other is 1
        if(deltaB > 0)
            replace(collision.bodyA, collision.normalB, deltaA); 

        if(deltaA > 0)
            replace(collision.bodyB, collision.normalA, deltaB);
    }

    private void replace(Body body, Vector2 normal, float delta) {
        body.getPosition().x += normal.x * delta; //body.getPosition() is a Vector2
        body.getPosition().y += normal.y * delta;
    }
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work properly and accumulates floating point precision error. The error is well handled by my collision detection which checks for float equality using ULP. However it breaks when crossing 0 because of the ULP going extremely low.

I could simply fix an epsilon for a physic simulation but it would remove the whole point of using floats. The technique I want to use lets the user choose his precision implicitly and theorically should be working with any precision.

Comment: Instead of doing this the hard way, Why don't you just use BigDecimal for arbitrary precision?
 (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: @Tezra Because I don't want to be infinitely precise, I just want to be 32 bits precise. Plus, it's a physics engine. The faster the better, I want to let the user have the biggest amount of physic bodies possible. My other solution would be fixed points but I decided to move away from that just to be more flexible with the user inputs that will most likely be floats as it's the most used for video games.

Comment: Another reason would be the garbage collector. I'm pooling mutable objects to prevent using the garbage collector which can affect performance for platforms like android. Using BigDecimal would mean making my own mutable BigDecimal class.

Comment: precision by Double data type is 52 bits. Not enough? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3

Comment: @ShaurabhBharti It is not an issue about the amount of precision but about mastering the float precision. You didn't get any of my question. If my explanation wasn't clear enough, can you tell me how to improve it ?

Comment: Interesting question. In case you don't get a decent answer, drop me comment in two days. I would be willing to put up a bounty here.

Comment: What you call a leap is also known as ULP unit of least precision (the value of least significand bit).

Comment: `Math.nextAfter(value, value + signum(leaps))` does not work, because `value + signum(leaps)` is the same as `value` for roughly half the values that `value` can take. Try `Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY * signum(leaps)`

Comment: i guess aka.nice's answer covers it. Just a little reminder: you are familiar with `strictfp`, right? you might need it

Comment: @nandsito `strictfp` ensures floating points operations to be the same on different machines. On the same machine, you will always get the same results even without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Underlying IEEE 754 floating point model has this property: if you re-interpret the bits as Integer, taking the next float after (or before depending on the direction) is just like taking the next (or previous) integer, that is adding or subtracting 1 to the bit pattern re-interpreted as integer.

Stepping n times is adding (or subtracting) n to the bit pattern. It's as simple as that as long as the sign does not change, and you don't overflow to NaN or Inf.

And the number of different floats between two floats is the difference of two integers if the signs agree.

If signs differ, since the float has a sign-magnitude like representation, which does not fit the integer representation, you'll then have to exert a bit of arithmetic.

Comment: Wouldn't the exponent be incremented when the mantissa overflows ? Would this be the correct behavior ?

Comment: Yes, it's the correct behavior if you consider n as the distance between two float in the representation. You can't get more bits from the float... So when you change binade, the ULP is multiplied/divided by 2. If what you want is start_float + n*ulp(start_float), then no, it's not the correct behaviour indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I want to do the same calculation. So, if "leaps" means as @aka.nice said, the integer difference/span/distance between two float-point values according to the IEEE 754 floating-point "single format" bit layout ([IEEE754 Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)), I may have found a simple method:

[public static native int floatToRawIntBits(float value)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Float.java) and [Java_java_lang_Float_floatToRawIntBits](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/native/java/lang/Float.c) can be used for this purpose, which has similar functionality to my test code in c++ ([reinterpret a memory](https://ideone.com/XzmlID)  ([reinterpret_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast))).

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44008357/adding-and-subtracting-exact-values-to-float */
int main(void) {
    float float0 = 1.5f;
    float float1 = 1.5000001f;
    int intbits_of_float0 = *(int *)&float0;
    int intbits_of_float1 = *(int *)&float1;

    printf("float %.17g is reinterpreted as an integer %d\n", float0, intbits_of_float0);
    printf("float %.17g is reinterpreted as an integer %d\n", float1, intbits_of_float1);

    return 0;
}
```

And, the Java code ([online compiler](https://ideone.com/4j96Ul)) below is used to calcuate the "leaps":

```
public class Toy {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int length = 0x82000000;
        int x = length >>> 24;
        int y = (length >>> 24) & 0xFF;

        System.out.println("length = " + length + ", x = " + x + ", y = " + y);

        float float0 = 1.5f;
        float float1 = 1.5000001f;
        float float2 = 1.5000002f;
        float float4 = 1.5000004f;
        float float5 = 1.5000005f;

        // testLeaps(float0, float4);
        // testLeaps(0, float5);
        // testLeaps(0, -float1);
        // testLeaps(-float1, 0);

        System.out.println(Math.nextAfter(-float1, Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY));
        System.out.println(INT_POWER_MASK & Float.floatToIntBits(-float0));
        System.out.println(INT_POWER_MASK & Float.floatToIntBits(float0));
        // testLeaps(-float1, -float0);
        testLeaps(-float0, 0);
        testLeaps(float0, 0);
    }

    public static void testLeaps(float value, float destination) {
        System.out.println("optLeaps(" + value + ", " + destination + ") = " + optLeaps(value, destination));
        System.out.println("getLeaps(" + value + ", " + destination + ") = " + getLeaps(value, destination));
    }

    public static final int INT_POWER_MASK = 0x7f800000 | 0x007fffff; // ~0x80000000
    /**
     * Retrieves the integer difference between two float-point values according to
     * the IEEE 754 floating-point "single format" bit layout.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * mask 0x80000000 | 0x7f800000            | 0x007fffff
     *            sign | exponent              | coefficient/significand/mantissa
     *              +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
     *              |  |                       |                                                                    |
     *              +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
     *               31 30                   23 22                                                                 0
     * 0x7fc00000 => NaN
     * 0x7f800000 +Infinity
     * 0xff800000 -Infinity
     * </pre>
     * 
     * Using base (radix) 10, the numerical value of such a float type number is
     * `(-1)^sign x coefficient x 10^exponent`, so the coefficient is a key factor
     * to calculation of leaps coefficient.
     * 
     * @param value       the first operand
     * @param destination the second operand
     * @return the integer span from {@code value} to {@code destination}
     */
    public static int optLeaps(float value, float destination) {
        // TODO process possible cases for some special inputs.

        int valueBits = Float.floatToIntBits(value); // IEEE 754 floating-point "single format" bit layout
        int destinationBits = Float.floatToIntBits(destination); // IEEE 754 floating-point "single format" bit layout
        int leaps; // Float.intBitsToFloat();
        if ((destinationBits ^ valueBits) >= 0) {
            leaps = Math.abs(destinationBits - valueBits);
        } else {
            leaps = INT_POWER_MASK & destinationBits + INT_POWER_MASK & valueBits;
        }
        return leaps;
    }

    public static int getLeaps(float value, float destination) {
        int leaps = 0;
        float signum = Math.signum(destination - value);

        // float direction = Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY * signum;
        // while (value * signum < destination * signum) {
        // value = Math.nextAfter(value, direction); // Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY * direction
        // leaps++;
        // }

        if (0 == signum) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (0 < signum) {
            while (value < destination) {
                value = Math.nextAfter(value, Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
                leaps++;
            }
        } else {
            while (value > destination) {
                value = Math.nextAfter(value, Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
                leaps++;
            }
        }
        return leaps;
    }

    // optimiaze to reduce the elapsed time by roughly half
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To start, I just want to say I don't like hacking into an Objects implementation, and you should using your own (or another library) implementation first, but sometimes you have to get creative.

Lets start with key detail here, what you call the "Leap" (I would call rounding error), So What/Why is there rounding error? Floats (and Doubles) are stored as Integer X Base_Integer^exponent_Integer. ([IEEE Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)) So using base 10, If you have 1.2340 X 10^3 (or 1,234.0) your "Leap" will be 0.1 since that is the size of your least significant digit (In storage, the . is implied).

(And I'm out, too much black magic here for me)

Comment: What I call "leap" is the integer amout of possible values between float a and float b. I want a way to get it from 2 floats and add it back into a float.

Comment: @Winter, The number of possible values between any 2 floats is Infinite. You have to put it into context of Significant Figures / Precision.

Comment: @Terza When talking of floating points It is obviously not. I mean the amount of float possible values.

Comment: @Winter Even with floats. Unless you are only working in the smallest float range (in which case, you don't need float), by shifting the exponent to the smallest range, Min-Max int on the left side are now all valid numbers between float a and b. Since the range +/-1 × 10^38 far exceeds +/- 2 X 10^9, you HAVE to work on Significant Figures / Precision. Counting possibilities is not a feasible option. Rounding errors are caused BECAUSE the difference in the two values are too large (with respect to their sig_figs/precision).

Comment: @Terza I don't want to shift them to get more precision, I want to be able to leap from floats to floats just like `Math.nextAfter` but for n times. (Without a loop, of course) I also need a function to get me how much floats there's between 2 floats without shifting it's precision. Such function should return 0 for that input: `100.00001, 100.000015`

As I said I could be using integers but I want to use floats to have an auto scalable precision and a giant range. That lets the user play with tiny or giant numbers without having to scale.

Comment: @Winter A float has a sign bit, A Number, and an exponent. (Base is 2 for binary) The number portion is the significant figures (24 bit window of number for single precision AKA float), and the exponent is the precision (how far to the left or right to shift your window from 1.00000) Any portion of your number that falls outside that 24 bit window gets dropped as a "rounding error" (with standard rules for handling different precision numbers). So, if you can explain your problem using base 10 Scientific Notation with base numbers +/- 1.000 and exponents +/- 100; I can help far better.

Comment: @Terza When rounding, It gets dropped to a specific value, this value I call it a possible float value. What I call a leap is a leap from a possible float value to another. (The amount of Math.nextAfter calls required to get from one to another) I haven't explained my problem with any base because it wouldn't change anything. But with base numbers +/- 1.000 and exponents +/- 100; an example would just be `100.1, 100.2` (basically 1.001 with e100). How much floats there is between the 2 numbers ? 0 since a float between these 2 numbers would round to 100.1 or 100.2.